# Illustration/visualisation of django web framework structure

Tags: python, django, http

It would be helpful if there were a "high level" (boxes and arrows) drawing illustrating the structure of the Django web framework. This would show the interaction between `views`,`URLconf`,`models`,`templates` etc and `HTTP` calls. Does such a thing exist?

**What high level illustrations, showing the structure of the django web framework, exist?**